# What is the meaning of ... in some MATLAB codes?

Tags: matlab

What is the meaning of `...` in some MATLAB codes?
e.g; consider the following code (copied from [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/object-detection-in-a-cluttered-scene-using-point-feature-matching.html)

```
[tform, inlierBoxPoints, inlierScenePoints] = ...
    estimateGeometricTransform(matchedBoxPoints, matchedScenePoints, 'affine');
Display the matching point pairs with the outliers removed

figure;
showMatchedFeatures(boxImage, sceneImage, inlierBoxPoints, ...
    inlierScenePoints, 'montage');
title('Matched Points (Inliers Only)');

    boxPolygon = [1, 1;...                         
            size(boxImage, 2), 1;...                 
            size(boxImage, 2), size(boxImage, 1);... 
            1, size(boxImage, 1);...                 
            1, 1];
```

What does happen if I do not use `...`? I have run my program without using these `...` and I see no difference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ellipsis (...) is used to indicate that an expression is to be continued in the next line. When an expression is very long, the text editor is not able to display the whole line at once. We use ellipsis so that everything in can be displayed at once (without the need to scroll to the right)

Answer (score 0):

`...`  This transfer of a long string to the next line.

---

[See this example to understand how it works](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/continue-long-statements-on-multiple-lines.html)